# How to make a cube expand as it moves in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Cheetah mobiles dancing line inspired me help me in this case how to make the cube expand in length in unity game engine.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the size of your cube by adding a Vector3(sizeToIncrease, sizeToIncrease, sizeToIncrease) to your transform.localScale. Like this:

```
if(moving){
    transform.localScale += new Vector3(sizeToIncrease, sizeToIncrease, 
sizeToIncrease);
}
```